# Two servers(services) on one machine (IP)

Tags: networking, server, apache2, samba, dns

I'm wondering, is there any option to run multiple servers or services on one device (Ubuntu server) on one IP?

For example
I want to install something similar to ActiveDirectory, let's say it will be Zentyal Server or 'clean' samba.
Then, i want to install a jabber server, and finally, an ownCloud server, and an Apache server.

I will have two interfeces on my machine. First to the WAN, and second to the LAN.

And now, user in my network will login on PC to the local domain accounts, then they will try to access some of these services. For example on local.domain.com will be availivable a website, on owncloud.domain.com - ownCloud service and on jabber.domain.com - jabber service.

What should i do? Add new enteries in DNS service and forward ports? 
Or a better idea is to set up these services on other local machines in LAN?

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number or services on one physical server with one IP address.

Different services will use different ports.

Comment: Ok, let's say a user will try to config a jabber account on Pidgin. He must insert port, that i configured earlier on jabber server (for example ejabbered). Right?

Comment: In most cases services have default ports. I do not know which one is used by jabber. You can keep the default setting. Then users won't need to change anything.

Comment: What about account name integration? Is there a simple way to do this? I mean, user will log in to the domain, and will he have already configured jabber account name or ownCloud login (same as on AD domain) ? Or, he should do such thing manually? Or maybe there is a script (or option to write a script) to do that automatically?

Comment: This is out of scope of your question and it is too broad.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting comments @Mario  And it is probably port 5222/TCP